# OGLFT draws text when GLStipple is used

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 2d

I have an interesting bug that has been "bugging" me for a few days now.

I am currently using OpenGL to draw text on a screen. I am utilizing the OGLFT library to assist the drawing. This library actually uses the freetype2 library. I am actually not doing anything special with the text. I am only looking for monochromatic text.

Anyways, after implementing the library, I noticed that the text is only drawn correct when I have glStipple enabled. I believe that there is some interference issue between the OGLFT library and what I am enabling.

I was wondering if there is anyone out there with some experience on using the OGLFT library. I am posting a minimalist example of my code to demonstrate what is going on:

(Please note that there are some variables that are used to st the zoom factor of my glCanvas and the position of the camera and that this is only for 2D)

```
double _zoomX = 1.0;

double _zoomY = 1.0;

double _cameraX = 0;

double _cameraY = 0;



/* This function gets called everytime a draw routine is needed */
void modelDefinition::onPaintCanvas(wxPaintEvent &event)
{
    wxGLCanvas::SetCurrent(*_geometryContext);// This will make sure the the openGL commands are routed to the wxGLCanvas object
    wxPaintDC dc(this);// This is required for drawing

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        updateProjection();

    OGLFT::Monochrome *testface = new OGLFT::Monochrome( "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf", 8);
        testface->draw(0, 0, "test");
        glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);// WHen I comment out this line, the text is unable to be drawn

        glLineStipple(1, 0b0001100011000110);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex2d(_startPoint.x, _startPoint.y);
            glVertex2d(_endPoint.x, _endPoint.y);
        glEnd();
        glDisable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);

    SwapBuffers();
}

void modelDefinition::updateProjection()
{
        // First, load the projection matrix and reset the view to a default view
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho(-_zoomX, _zoomX, -_zoomY, _zoomY, -1.0, 1.0);

    //Reset to modelview matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glViewport(0, 0, (double)this->GetSize().GetWidth(), (double)this->GetSize().GetHeight());
    /* This section will handle the translation (panning) and scaled (zooming). 
     * Needs to be called each time a draw occurs in order to update the placement of all the components */
    if(_zoomX < 1e-9 || _zoomY < 1e-9)
    {
        _zoomX = 1e-9;
        _zoomY = _zoomX;
    }

    if(_zoomX > 1e6 || _zoomY > 1e6)
    {
        _zoomX = 1e6;
        _zoomY = _zoomX;
    }

    glTranslated(-_cameraX, -_cameraY, 0.0);
}
```

Also one thing to note is that the code below the `glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);` is required. It is as if the glStipple needs to be drawn correctly for the text to be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through your code, I believe that your intention is to render it as a greyscale? If so, then you can simply use the `OGLFT::Grayscale *testface = new OGLFT::Grayscale( "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf", 8);`

This will get what you need without having to worry about the issue that you posted. In fact, I recommend doing it this way too.

Comment: Yes! That was it, everything works now. Thank you so much!